# Validate login form through JavaScript (Suggestion)

Tags: javascript, validation, forms

I have used pure JavaScript to validate this login form consider the below example and also check out the live demo here https://codepen.io/uicreation/pen/xpdbKe

hope it will be help you to understand how JavaScript validation is works.

[Live Demo](https://codepen.io/uicreation/pen/xpdbKe)

```js
if(document.getElementsByClassName('firstForm')[0]){
  document.getElementsByClassName('firstForm')[0].onsubmit = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var field = this;
    var email = field.querySelector('input[type=email]');
    var pass = field.querySelector('input[type=password]');
    var regex = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    if(!regex.test(email.value)){
     console.log("enter a valid email address")
    } else if(pass.value.length < 8){
      console.log("password should be greater than 8 characters")
    } else {
      console.log("success!")
    }
  }
}
```

```css
form {
  margin: 30px 0 0 30px;
}
  fieldset {
    padding:5px;
  }
    label {
    min-width:60px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
    input[type=submit]{
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-left:5px;
  }
```

```html
  <form class="firstForm" novalidate>
<fieldset>
<label>Email</label>
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email" />
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<label>Password</label>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password" />
</fieldset>

<input type="submit" value="Login" />
  </form>
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: @gurvinder372  It doesn't have any issue. I have trying to explain how does we can validate form through pure JavaScript.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP doesn't have any issue.

Comment: You could at very last ask a question and answer it yourself if you really think you have the right answer to a never asked before problem.. Unfortunately that's not the case, validation in JS has dozens of questions, probably new dupes almost every day. And you don't explain anything, while your answer is not even fully fonctional, as the form will never actually submit..

Comment: @Kaddath appreciate your words and i will remember it for the next time before i will do something like this.